# how do I extract the PID from the output of `lsof -i:8080`?

Tags: bash

Each time I need to stop the process that is occupying port 8080, I have to run this command first

```
$ lsof -i:8080
```

to get the PID

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  4024 ubuntu    3u  IPv4 2181080      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

and then I kill the PID

```
kill 4024
```

I'd like to write a script to make it simple, how do I extract the PID from the output of `lsof -i:8080`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the `lsof -i:8080` output to `awk` to get the PID:

```
lsof -i:8080 | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'
```

You can then combine it with `kill`:

```
kill $(lsof -i:8080 | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}')
```

You can also create a Bash function and add it at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
function kill8080()
{
    kill $(lsof -i:8080 | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}')
}
```

I named the above function `kill8080`, but you can name it as you wish.